# ValueError during using 'try except'formula

Tags: python, valueerror

I have a list:

```
['x', '-', '1', '=', '5']
```

This is the code that I wrote:

```
if (a[1]) == '+':
    try:
        print(int(int(a[0])+int(a[2])))
    except ValueError:
        print(int(int(a[0])+int(a[4])))
    except ValueError:
        print(int(int(a[2])+int(a[4])))

if (a[1]) == '-':
    try:
        print(int(int(a[0])-int(a[2])))
    except ValueError:
        print(int(int(a[0])-int(a[4])))
    except ValueError:
        print(int(int(a[4])-int(a[2])))
```

however this 'try except' shows following error and can not run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Main.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(int(int(a[0])-int(a[2]))) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Main.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(int(int(a[0])-int(a[4]))) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'
```

Can anyone please advise me how to fix this code?

When I run with the list:

```
['1', '+', '3', '=', 'x']
```

this does works.

Comment: What do you expect `int('x')` to equal?

Comment: You also don't need to have multiple `int` casts. An integer added to or subtracted from another integer is always an integer.

Comment: There's no point having two `except ValueError` blocks for the same `try` block.

Comment: The additional `except ValueError` line won't catch additional exceptions raised in the preceding `ValueError` except handler. You'd have to use another `try ... except`, nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs inside the `except`, and there is no `try` that handles the error inside the `except`, so the error propagates.

Put a `try` inside the excepts so they don't error.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here, is related to your except! When using multiple, each one should cover a single exception, and you're using the same exception for both, and this is causing the program to don't run properly.

Besides that, there are a few problems with your code (luckily there's an easy solution for them):
1) You're using too many cast int() without needed -> Once you use int(a[n]), it's already an integer, so there's no need to redo it in the result of the operation
2) You're overly complicating your logic for receiving the operation string and transform it in the arithmetic operator

To solve this, my suggestion would be:

```
import operator

operators = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.truediv,
    '%' : operator.mod,
    '^' : operator.xor,
}

# Got to find which are the digits to operate
numbersToOperate = [int(a[i]) for i in (0,2,4) if a[i].isdigit()]

if (a[0] == str(numbersToOperate[0])):
    print(operators[a[1]](numbersToOperate[0], numbersToOperate[1]))
else:
    print(operators[a[1]](numbersToOperate[1], numbersToOperate[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish I could be a programmer like you